# merge rows with reversed columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe, and I would like to merge the rows that has the same value in reversed columns. An example as below:

```
Column1 Column2
A       B
B       A
C       D
D       C
E       F
```

Expected results:

```
Column1 Column2
A       B
C       D
E       F
```

As the file has less than 50 lines (though I have 1000 files), I tried some codes use `iterrows` as followed:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    output = []
    row_rev = df[(df['Column1'] == row['Column2']) & (df['Column2'] == row['Column1'])]
    row_rev_index = df[(df['Column1'] == row['Column2']) & (df['Column2'] == row['Column1'])].index()
    if row_rev.any():
        print(df[min([index, row_rev_index])])
        output.append(df[min([index, row_rev_index])]) # always print out the first line of the reciprocal lines
```

but it complains that `row_rev_index = df[(df['Column1'] == row['Column2']) & (df['Column2'] == row['Column1'])].index()` `TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
row_rev_index = df[(df['Column1'] == row['Column2']) & (df['Column2'] == row['Column1'])].index()
```

to

```
row_rev_index = df[(df['Column1'] == row['Column2']) & (df['Column2'] == row['Column1'])].index
```

or even shorter

```
row_rev_index = row_rev.index
```

Comment: when I `print(row_rev_index)`, and it gives `Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')`. Is this correct? though 2 is the index indeed, but I was thinking about an integer.

Comment: `df.loc[row_rev_index]` gives the correct row.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
df = df.groupby(df.apply(lambda x: tuple(set(x)),axis=1)).first()
```